# Writing a Functional test using Intern and Chai

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chai, intern

I have written the following test using Intern and Chai. The Assert does not work as expected. I am trying to do string comparison but the test always passes when it should fail if the strings are different. I using a chromedriver for local selenium. My test is as follows -

```
define([
   'intern!object',
   'intern/chai!expect',
   'intern/chai!assert',
   'require'
   ], function (registerSuite, expect, assert, require) {
   registerSuite({
     name: 'testing readmore',
     submit: function () {
        return this.remote
        .get('/')
         .setFindTimeout(200)
         .findByClassName('link')
         .click()
         .end()
         .findByClassName('readMore-margin-collapse')
         .then(function(element) {
          console.log(element);
              element.getComputedStyle('overflow')
              .then(function (value) {
                    assert.strictEqual('value', 'hidden',
                           'should return value of overflow');
              });
         });                 
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

`element.getComputedStyle` is an asynchronous function so you have to `return` it.